# Cordova Facebook Like Button Overrides Webview

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Cordova 3.4.0 iOS 7 app using the official Facebook Connect plugin. It works fine for native FB login / integration. If I manually call FB.ui feed dialog via Javascript, it also pops up a smaller layer on screen with the feed dialog options, or asks user to login if they haven't done so.

The problem lies in the Like button, which I am generating via a HTML5 code like:

If I tap on this Like button, it opens a full screen FB login page that completely overrides the current Cordova app window, and there's no way to go back anymore. It takes over the entire webview.

I can't figure out why it only happens to the Like button. I would presume that its login popup dialog would also be the same as that of FB.ui's smaller layered dialog box. Is it somehow not compatible with the Facebook Connect plugin, or using a different UI?

Can someone please advise on how I can properly implement a Facebook Like button within Cordova + Facebook Connect plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom **Like** button & follow [this](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#how-do-i-add-a-like-button). It is right now possible using graph API.